# $\sin(4x)y''-2(1+\cos(4x))y'=\tan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

looking for more friendly way for the following second order ode, thanks in advance
$$
\sin(4x)y''-2(1+\cos(4x))y'=\tan(x)\\
$$
integration factor
$$
\mu(x) = e^{-2\int\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{\sin(4x)}dx}
$$
make long short:
$$
\mu(x) = \sin(2x)\sin(4x)\cos(2x)
$$
now for the order reduction
$$
u=y'\\
\sin(4x)u'-2(1+\cos(4x))u=\tan(x)\\
$$
$$
\left[u \cdot (\sin(2x)\sin(4x)\cos(2x)\right]'= \frac{\tan(x)}{\sin(4x)}\sin(2x)\sin(4x)\cos(2x)
$$
integrating right side
$$
u \cdot (\sin(2x)\sin(4x)\cos(2x)) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{8}\sin(4x)
$$
now all left is to integrate u to get y, however it's seems it isn't the right way...
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(4x)y''-2(1+\cos(4x))y'=\tan(x)\\$$
$$\sin(2x) \cos (2x)y''-2 \cos^2 (2x)y'=\dfrac 12 \tan(x)$$
$$\sin(2x) y''-2 \cos (2x))y'=\dfrac {\tan(x)}{2 \cos (2x)}$$
$$ \left (\dfrac  {y'}{ \sin (2x) } \right)'=\dfrac {\tan(x)}{\sin (2x) \sin (4x)}$$
$$  {y'}={ \sin (2x) }  \int \dfrac {dx}{2\cos^2 (x) \sin (4x)}$$
$$I=-\dfrac 14 \int \dfrac {du}{u(u+1)(1-u^2)}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{du}=\dfrac 18 \int \dfrac {du}{u(u+1)(1-u^2)}$$
Where $u= \cos (2x)$.

Comment: Much easier (as usual) ! Merry Xmas

Comment: Thanks Claude @ClaudeLeibovici  Merry Xhristmas too.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to solve the homogeneous equation:
$$\sin(4x)y_h^{\prime\prime}-2(1+\cos(4x))y_h^{\prime}=0$$
So
$$\frac{y_h^{\prime\prime}}{y_h^{\prime}}=\frac{2(1+\cos(4x))}{\sin(4x)}=2\cot(2x)$$
With integral $\ln\left(y_h^{\prime}\right)=\ln(\sin(2x))+C_1$ so $y_h^{\prime}=C_2\sin(2x)$. Then
$$y_h=-\frac12C_2\cos(2x)+C_3=C_4\cos(2x)+C_3$$
With this integral in hand we let $y(x)=u(x)\cos(2x)+v(x)$. Then
$$y^{\prime}=u^{\prime}\cos(2x)+v^{\prime}-2u\sin(2x)=-2u\sin(2x)$$
Where we have constrained $v^{\prime}=-u^{\prime}\cos(2x)$. Then $y^{\prime\prime}=-2u^{\prime}\sin(2x)-4u\cos(2x)$ and we have
$$\begin{align}\sin(4x)y^{\prime\prime}-2(1+\cos(4x))y^{\prime}&=-2u^{\prime}\sin(2x)\sin(4x)-8u\sin(2x)\cos^2(2x)\\
&\quad+8u\cos^2(2x)\sin(2x)\\
&=-4u^{\prime}\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)=\tan x\end{align}$$
So we have
$$\begin{align}u^{\prime}&=-\frac14\frac{\sin x}{4\sin^2x\cos^3x(2\cos^2x-1)}\\
&=-\frac1{16}\frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2x)\cos^3x(2\cos^2x-1)}\\
&=-\frac{\sin x}{16}\left(-\frac3{\cos x}-\frac{\frac12}{1+\cos x}+\frac{\frac12}{1-\cos x}-\frac1{\cos^3x}+\frac{8\cos x}{2\cos^2x-1}\right)\end{align}$$
And
$$u(x)=\frac1{16}\left(-3\ln\cos x-\ln\sin x+\frac12\sec^2x+2\ln\cos(2x)\right)+C_5$$
Then
$$\begin{align}v^{\prime}&=-u^{\prime}\cos(2x)=\frac1{16}\frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2x)\cos^3x}\\
&=\frac{\sin x}{16}\left(\frac1{\cos^3x}+\frac1{\cos x}-\frac{\frac12}{1+\cos x}+\frac{\frac12}{1-\cos x}\right)\end{align}$$
And
$$v(x)=\frac1{16}\left(\frac12\sec^2x+\ln\tan x\right)+C_6$$
Which implies that
$$\begin{align}y(x)&=\frac1{16}\left(-3\ln\cos x-\ln\sin x+\frac12\sec^2x+2\ln\cos(2x)\right)\cos(2x)\\
&\quad+C_5\cos(2x)+\frac1{16}\left(\frac12\sec^2x+\ln\tan x\right)+C_6\\
&=\frac1{16}\left(-3\ln\cos x-\ln\sin x+2\ln\cos(2x)\right)\cos(2x)\\
&\quad+C_5\cos(2x)+\frac1{16}\ln\tan x+C_7\end{align}$$
I haven't been able to figure out how to check this with Wolfram Alpha; maybe you will have better luck than I did.